# Implementation of memset_s based on C11 standard

Tags: c, memory-management, c11

The following code attempts to implement `memset_s()` based on [section K.3.7.4.1 of the ISO/IEC 9899:201x N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A1353%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C792%2C0%5D):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

errno_t memset_s(void *s,rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n)
{
    errno_t violation_present = 0;  

    volatile unsigned char * v = s;

    if ( s == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"memset_s: Error: void * s == NULL!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    if ( n > RSIZE_MAX )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"memset_s: Warning: rsize_t n > RSIZE_MAX!\n");  

        violation_present = 1;
    }

    if ( n > smax )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"memset_s: Warning: rsize_t n > rsize_t smax!\n");   

        violation_present = 1;


    }

    if ( smax > RSIZE_MAX )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"memset_s: Error: rsize_t smax > RSIZE_MAX!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    volatile unsigned char * v_p = &v[0];

    rsize_t i = 0;

    if ( violation_present == 1 ) // && (s != NULL) && (smax <= RSIZE_MAX) )
    {

        i = 0;

        while ( i < smax )
        {
            *v_p++ = (unsigned char)c; 

            i++;
        }   



        return violation_present;

    }


    else // no runtime-constraint violation found       
    {
        i = 0;


        while ( i < n )
        {
            *v_p++ = (unsigned char)c;

            i++;
        }



        return violation_present;

    }


}
```

I have also made a C source test file for `memset_s()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 8

typedef struct Node
{

    struct Node * link;

    int val;

} Node;


int main(void)
{
    errno_t result = 0; 

    printf("This program only checks for runtime-constraint\n"
        "violations in an invocation of memset_s.\n\n"
          );

    static char test[ARRAY_SIZE];

    printf("Does memset_s return nonzero value when void * s"
        " == NULL?\n\n"
          );

    result = memset_s(NULL,sizeof(test),0,sizeof(test));

    printf("Return Value: %llu\n\n",result);

    printf("Does memset_s return nonzero value when smax >"
        " RSIZE_MAX?\n\n"
          );

    result = memset_s(test,RSIZE_MAX+1,0,sizeof(test));

    printf("Return Value: %llu\n\n",result);

    printf("Does memset_s set the inputted char value into\n"
        "each of the first smax characters of the object\n"
        "pointed to by void *s only when there is a\n"
        "violation and void * s != NULl and when rsize_t\n"
        "smax is less than or equal to RSIZE_MAX and return\n"
        "nonzero value?\n\n"
          );

    result = memset_s(test,8*sizeof(char),84,RSIZE_MAX+1);

    printf("Return Value: %llu\n\n",result);

    printf("test string set with memset_s:\n%s\n",test);

    for ( rsize_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        test[i] = '\0';

    }

    printf("Does memset_s correctly set the inputted char value\n"
        "into each of the first n characters of the object\n"
        "pointed to by void *s when there is NO runtime\n"
        "constraint violation?\n\n"
          );

    result = memset_s(test,8*sizeof(char),84,4*sizeof(char));

    printf("Return Value: %llu\n\n",result);

    printf("test string set with memset_s for first four char\n" 
        "elements in a char array of 8 elements:\n%s\n\n",
        test
          );

    printf("Does memset_s only set the first smax values when\n"
        "rsize_t n > rsize_t smax?\n\n"
          );

    for ( rsize_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        test[i] = '\0';

    }

    result = memset_s(test,8*sizeof(char),84,8*sizeof(char)+1);

    printf("Return Value: %llu\n\n",result);

    printf("test string below:\n%s\n\n", 
        test
          );

    printf("Does memset_s correctly allocate unsigned chars to objects\n"
        "that in turn, store other objects, like a struct?\n"
        "In the example below, a struct Node of a Linked List\n"
        "is initialized through memset_s\n\n"
          );


    Node * node;

    result = memset_s(node,sizeof(Node),0,sizeof(Node));

    printf("Return Value: %llu\n\n",result);

    printf("node->link == %p\n",node->link);

    printf("node->val == %d\n\n",node->val);

    printf("Does memset_s do what was tested previously except that\n"
        "it initializes with a nonzero unsigned char value? In the\n"
        "example below, a second struct Node name node_two is\n"
        "initialized with the unsigned char value 84\n\n"
          );

    Node * node_two;

    Node * node_three;

    result = memset_s(node_two,sizeof(Node),84,sizeof(Node));

    printf("Return Value: %llu\n\n",result);

    printf("node_two->link == %p\n",node_two->link);

    printf("node_two->val == %d\n\n",node_two->val);

    printf("node_two->val in Hexadecimal format == 0x%x\n\n",node_two->val);

    return 0;

}
```

My only concern is that I forgot to find a security flaw in my implementation of `memset_s()`. Did I forget to test for any values?

I plan to use `memset_s()` in [my implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanveerasalim/SSL-TLS/master/ch1/my_http_c11.c) of http.c from the book "*Implementing SSL/TLS Using Cryptography and PKI*" by Joshua Davies.

Comment: Is this actually meant to be [tag:c99] code to implement a [tag:c11] feature?  With appropriate definitions of `rsize_t`, `errno_t` and `RSIZE_MAX`, it compiles fine as C99, so perhaps that's the tag that makes more sense?

Comment: You are aware that the optional Annex K is largely seen as politically motivated and a serious misstep? See [the tag-wiki on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tr24731/info) and questions under it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Warning messages

When we print fixed strings, it's better to use plain `fputs()` rather than the much more complex `fprintf()`.

However, in this case, the diagnostic output should be removed: such side-effects are not part of the contract of `memset_s()`, and are actively harmful (because the whole point of the checks is to report errors to the calling program, which *knows better than the library* what a user needs to be told).

## Don't write `for` loops as `while`

Either

```
    for (rsize_t i = 0u;  i < smax;  ++i)
    {
        *v++ = (unsigned char)c;
    }
```

or

```
    while (smax-- > 0)
    {
        *v++ = (unsigned char)c;
    }
```

(I removed the unnecessary `v_p` variable).

## Unnecessary duplication

Instead of writing the loop twice, we can simply adjust `n`:

```
if ( n > smax )
{
    n = smax;
    violation_present = EINVAL;
}
```

This gives us an improved and much shorter `memset_s()`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

errno_t memset_s(void *s, rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n)
{    
    if (!s || smax > RSIZE_MAX) {
        return EINVAL;
    }

    errno_t violation_present = 0;
    if (n > smax) {
        n = smax;
        violation_present = EINVAL;
    }

    volatile unsigned char *v = s;
    for (rsize_t i = 0u;  i < n;  ++i) {
        *v++ = (unsigned char)c;
    }

    return violation_present;
}
```

Alternatively, re-entering the function instead of tracking `violation_present`:

```
errno_t memset_s(void *s, rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n)
{
    if (!s || smax > RSIZE_MAX) {
        return EINVAL;
    }

    if (n > smax) {
        memset_s(s, smax, c, smax);
        return EINVAL;
    }

    volatile unsigned char *v = s;
    for (rsize_t i = 0u;  i < n;  ++i) {
        *v++ = (unsigned char)c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Constraint handlers

I'm going to assume that the lack of support for constraint handlers ([section K.3.6.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A1319%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C792%2C0%5D)) is intentional, and that you don't intend to set a constraint handler in your calling code.

---

## Test program

It's a serious error to format `errno_t` values (which are `int` according to the definition) as if they were `long long unsigned int`.  All those `%llu` must be changed to `%d` or `%i`.

The pointer values printed using `%p` format need to be cast to `void*` (remember, a varargs function has no way of passing other pointer types).

`sizeof (char)` is one by definition, since the result is in units of `char`.

The most serious problem is that `node` and `node_two` are used without initializing them to anything.  This causes a crash for me, but if you're unlucky you might get a program that runs successfully.  Suitable compiler warnings should alert you to this problem (and the format string mismatches I mentioned).

The test program should be self-checking: instead of producing a stream of output that must be inspected, report only the failures, and use the exit status to indicate whether the entire test was successful.

Here's a version that does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* returns error count: 0 on success and 1 on failure */
int test_memset(const char *message, const char *file, unsigned int line,
                errno_t expected,
                void *s, rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n)
{
    if (memset_s(s, smax, c, n) == expected) {
        return 0;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u: %s\n", file, line, message);
    return 1;
}


int main(void)
{
    char test[8] = "abcdefgh";
    int error_count = 0;

    error_count += test_memset("s==NULL should return error", __FILE__, __LINE__, EINVAL,
                               NULL, sizeof test, 0, sizeof test);

#if RSIZE_MAX+1 > RSIZE_MAX
    error_count += test_memset("smax > RSIZE_MAX should return error", __FILE__, __LINE__, EINVAL,
                               test, RSIZE_MAX+1, 0, sizeof test);

    /* should still have cleared the data */
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < sizeof test;  ++i) {
        if (test[i] == '\0') {
            fputs("smax > RSIZE_MAX prevent writing\n", stderr);
            ++error_count;
            break;
        }
    }
#endif /* else, RSIZE_MAX==SIZE_MAX, and no caller can provide an out-of-range value */


    error_count += test_memset("When runtime constraints satisfied, should return success", __FILE__, __LINE__, 0,
                               test, sizeof test, '*', 4);

    /* should have written the first 4 chars */
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < 4;  ++i) {
        if (test[i] != '*') {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u: Should have written * at position %zu\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, i);
            ++error_count;
            break;
        }
    }

    /* should not have written after the first 4 chars */
    for (size_t i = 4;  i < sizeof test;  ++i) {
        if (test[i] == '*') {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u: Should not have written '%c' at position %zu\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, test[i], i);
            ++error_count;
            break;
        }
    }

    memset(test, '\0', sizeof test);

    error_count += test_memset("n > smax should set first smax chars and return error", __FILE__, __LINE__, EINVAL,
                               test, 4, '*', 8);

    /* should have written the first 4 chars */
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < 4;  ++i) {
        if (test[i] != '*') {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u: Should have written * at position %zu\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, i);
            ++error_count;
            break;
        }
    }

    /* should not have written after the first 4 chars */
    for (size_t i = 4;  i < sizeof test;  ++i) {
        if (test[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u: Should not have written '%c' at position %zu\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, test[i], i);
            ++error_count;
            break;
        }
    }

    return error_count;
}
```

I took out the tests that had dangling `Node` pointers; it wasn't clear what they are supposed to achieve.

Comment: I haven't mentioned anything here about performance in this review - it's probably sufficient to say that better implementations don't use a char-by-char loop like that, but write in chunks of the platform's largest addressable units as much as possible.

Comment: Well Toby, I think your while loop fix for copy data and ideas for program testing are indeed correct!

Comment: @Tanveer - I made a serious oversight: `n > RSIZE_MAX `shouldn't inhibit writing if `s` and `smax` are both valid.  See latest edit.

Comment: "it's better to use plain fputs() rather than the much more complex fprintf()." --> is of reduced value as good compilers will analyze known functions and emit efficient code either way.

Comment: `RSIZE_MAX+1` could be 0 and render the test ineffective.

Comment: `EINVAL` is not in the C spec.  Could do something like `#ifdef EINVAL #define my_EINVAL #else #define my_EINVAL 1` and return that.

Comment: Answer well uses `volatile`, yet I did not see "why" explained.

Comment: @chux - no need to explain why the `volatile` is important, since it was perfectly fine in the original code.    I suppose it could have been worth a brief "this is good" comment, but I was focusing more on what could be improved.

Comment: `RSIZE_MAX+1` can indeed be zero, although "*For implementations targeting machines with large address spaces,
it  is  recommended  that
`RSIZE_MAX`
be  defined  as  the  smaller  of  the  size  of  the  largest
object  supported  or
`(SIZE_MAX >> 1)`*".  We can conditionalize that test.  Plain `fputs()` is still a good habit for fixed strings - it means we don't need to look for embedded `%` characters and/or write a `"%s"` format string.

Answer (score 3):

```
errno_t memset_s(void *s,rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n)
```

You've got a missing space after that first comma. (Sure, inconsistent whitespace doesn't affect functionality; but like any spelling mistake, it indicates that you haven't proofread your code. Which means it *probably* has some other one-character typos too. Some of which *might* affect functionality. Always read your code after writing it!)

The typedef `errno_t` is invariably `int`. So personally I'd just write `int` — unless you were planning to use the association with `errno` in some significant way. Right now your code just returns `0` on success and `1` (which is to say `EPERM`) on failure. Consider whether `memset_s` should return a more specific and helpful errno than simply `EPERM`. For example, maybe if you pass NULL to it, you should get back `EINVAL` "Invalid argument"?

However, at the same time, [YAGNI](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) — it may be counterproductive to spend a lot of time agonizing over what are the proper errno return values, unless you have an actual use-case for these return values. The only reason to return `EINVAL` for a null argument instead of the generic `EPERM` is that it enables a caller to detect that specific error case and handle the error accordingly. *But the caller can already detect that case!* The caller doesn't need your help to detect `s == NULL`! The caller controls the value of `s` in the first place, and can easily check for null beforehand, if they think it's possible for `s` to be null. (And if it's *not* possible for `s` to be null, then there's no point checking inside `memset_s` either. That's just a waste of CPU cycles.)

Can you tell that I think `memset_s` is largely a waste of time, design-wise? :)

---

I find your chain of `if`s difficult to match up to the specification. The specification is as follows:

> **Runtime-constraints:** `s` shall not be a null pointer. Neither `smax` nor `n` shall be greater than `RSIZE_MAX`. `n` shall not be greater than `smax`.
>
> If there is a runtime-constraint violation, then if `s` is not a null pointer and `smax` is not greater than `RSIZE_MAX`, the `memset_s` function stores the value of `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) into each of the first `smax` characters of the object pointed to by `s`.
>
> **Description:** The `memset_s` function copies the value of `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) into each of the first `n` characters of the object pointed to by `s`.

So I would naturally implement it something like this:

```
errno_t memset_s(void *s, rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n) {
    bool violation = (s == NULL) || (smax > RSIZE_MAX) || (n > RSIZE_MAX) || (n > smax);
    if (violation) {
        if ((s != NULL) && !(smax > RSIZE_MAX)) {
            for (rsize_t i = 0; i < smax; ++i) {
                ((volatile unsigned char*)s)[i] = c;
            }
        }
        return EPERM;
    } else {
        for (rsize_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            ((volatile unsigned char*)s)[i] = c;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That seems to implement the specification 100% correctly, line for line.

You write the second `for`-loop above as

```
    i = 0;


    while ( i < n )
    {
        *v_p++ = (unsigned char)c;

        i++;
    }
```

(yes, with *two* blank lines between the `i = 0` and the rest of the loop). That's definitely too much code for a simple `for`-loop. Even without doing anything else to your code, you could replace those 9 lines with 3 lines:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        *v_p++ = (unsigned char)c;
    }
```

A 66% reduction in lines-of-code is not bad for a day's work!

---

```
volatile unsigned char * v = s;
// ...
volatile unsigned char * v_p = &v[0];
```

You know that `&v[0]` is the same thing as `v`, right?

---

```
rsize_t i = 0;

if ( violation_present == 1 ) // && (s != NULL) && (smax <= RSIZE_MAX) )
{

    i = 0;
```

Three things:

- You initialize `i` to `0`, and then *again* initialize it to `0`. Are you worried that the first initialization might not have taken? :)
- The commented-out code is confusing. (I left a comment on the question referring to this and some other commented-out code; you did remove some of it, but left this snippet commented out.) If you meant for this code to take effect, you should uncomment it. If you meant for this code *not* to take effect, you should just delete it. Don't leave commented-out code hanging around. (If it's for historical interest, you should learn `git` or some other version-control system.)
- You branch on if `violation_present == 1`. This suggests that `violation_present` might take on other values, such as `0` (which it does) or `2` or `42` (which it does not). The compiler will likely generate code to compare `violation_present` against the constant `1`. But actually all you mean here is "If there's a violation present...", which is idiomatically expressed as `if (violation_present) ...`. Furthermore, you should look up the `bool` type (defined in `<stdbool.h>`) — it's tailor-made for boolean variables that can only ever take on the value `true` or `false`. (Notice the use of `bool` in my reference implementation above.)

---

```
fprintf(stderr,"memset_s: Error: void * s == NULL!\n");
```

Missing whitespace again.

Here you have a `memset_s` function, whose job is to set a range of bytes to a value... and you've got it pulling in `fprintf` from the standard library! Does that seem appropriate to you?

`memset_s` is a very low-level function. It should be usable even on embedded systems that have never heard of `fprintf` or `stderr`. You should find a way to report errors that doesn't involve `<stdio.h>`. (Might I suggest `errno_t`? :))

Comment: " it indicates that you haven't proofread your code." --> indicates an auto formatter was not used.  Better to auto-format that spend valuable time manual formating.

Comment: "you should get back EINVAL" --> `EINVAL, EPERM` are not specified in the C spec.